# How to post to a Resp API with Angular5 (x-www-form-urlencoded)

Tags: httpclient, angular5

My question is simple, but I do not find the solution. I need to post a body like this :
- key : username value : moi
- key : paswd value : root
-...
It work with postman, but when I try with angular 5 I do not have the response :

```
readonly ROOT_URL = 'localhost:8080/auth/';

getToken() {
const data: Post = {
username: 'root',
passwords: 'root',
grant_type: 'password',
client_id: 'admin-cli'
}
this.token = this.http.post(this.ROOT_URL,data, headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')); 
}
```

When I post the query in Postman I receive a token, and I need to stock that.

Answer (score 0):

The Angular `http.post` request doesn't return the data, it returns an *observable* of the data.  Use `subscribe` on an observable to get the data out of it.

```
this.http
    .post(
        this.ROOT_URL,
        data, 
        {headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')}
    )
    .map(res => res.json())
    .subscribe(data => this.token = data)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
readonly ROOT_URL = 'localhost:8080/auth/realms/demo/protocol/openid-connect/token';
posts : any;    

constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

getToken() {
const data: Post = {
username: 'root',
passwords: 'root',
grant_type: 'password',
client_id: 'admin-cli'
}
this.http.post(this.ROOT_URL,data, {headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')}).subscribe(data => this.token = data)}
}
```

but I do not receive the token like in postman

```
{
"access_token": "eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCIgOiAiSldUIiwia2lkIiA6ICJidFFTaGZBUDBpazVTTEFTOWZMRE4tbWxXZ3dvRnYwODVPZHpjSUJrWC13In0.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.VCe9YbIDRNbcC5uRFZIAtAbr3-VyuO6K8L3piPYq8ov3Gtwe1U-0YtCpnNOVM0bhUq1C9LDSk2g-bDWRU_BuZ-ZGV2Lh0uSGeOQzJH2p8dp6J6j44qrRvH5AFSv3dFOXA8X5U3rbzrfKDQE0CWBuFr91x9AjKlknnuNNMlM_2bKWjkSnhdo03gfVTPMQ0yrxAQA3SwM5ih4p7fiEbdPOtMn4riCyH5MgS02qexQQ3jUJ1XwGga3IqjdPW-i7sy7SqlaC-sNlQGqxlR_izrTfVhIgdQeBA7GLm23ljJ59Ino7reQTLILUEhKlEGjYVltk9sJIx_wXJ_PfjZK42o6cRw",
"expires_in": 300,
"refresh_expires_in": 1800,
"refresh_token": "eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCIgOiAiSldUIiwia2lkIiA6ICJidFFTaGZBUDBpazVTTEFTOWZMRE4tbWxXZ3dvRnYwODVPZHpjSUJrWC13In0.eyJqdGkiOiIzOWJlMGIyZi01OWJhLTQzYzUtODRkMC03YWFhYTg4ZTQ5ODYiLCJleHAiOjE1MTk0MTkzNjcsIm5iZiI6MCwiaWF0IjoxNTE5NDE3NTY3LCJpc3MiOiJodHRwOi8vbG9jYWxob3N0OjgwODAvYXV0aC9yZWFsbXMvZGVtbyIsImF1ZCI6ImFkbWluLWNsaSIsInN1YiI6IjNkYTY2MDYxLTQ2ZjUtNDZmYi1hNjllLTgwNGEzODkyMWQzMiIsInR5cCI6IlJlZnJlc2giLCJhenAiOiJhZG1pbi1jbGkiLCJhdXRoX3RpbWUiOjAsInNlc3Npb25fc3RhdGUiOiI2NzM4ZGFiYS01NGZiLTRkNzItODI1Mi04M2Y5N2M1MGU4NmUiLCJyZXNvdXJjZV9hY2Nlc3MiOnt9fQ.fdEQizXxwBA3pobOuVTQTyWiglq-DJFhx0X4BM-yzyJW9zWlrnzgsLtLZGp7jg3zSI0lOLufWufDtAgea1Y33hq2bqcXLhDXHm842XBj96lxshNwZrDngB9L2FAwrX-X_l3aDB1UPwOwXroINL8L7a7-3ywEuy0A-NoqlWLopPZAe6DBZVXT-6D8wzAJ_DS2KF2d-_IQVrzTnReDLjTNe_2bZVj_PIwBu7wriSOqlaoX79De4dmI8ElwvhaypAJggh5ZPqyqp3-FMIrdb9-5IaloBdHcPFMtJ2ZthKnJLqNvXlRD_jrbRSpLvyZjF_NgqjCuBBteGcprcReFGgm3Pw",
"token_type": "bearer",
"not-before-policy": 0,
"session_state": "6738daba-54fb-4d72-8252-83f97c50e86e"
```

}

Comment: Could you edit the post and show what value you're getting?  You can log it to the console with  `.subscribe(data => console.log(data))`

Comment: I edited my answer, I forgot to extract the json from the response

Comment: I have this error : ERROR ReferenceError: HttpHeaders is not defined

Comment: are you importing it with `import { HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';`

Comment: Yes I have forgotten thank you but now : Failed to load localhost:8080/auth/realms/demo/protocol/openid-connect/token: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.

Comment: That sounds like [this](http://ahmed.amayem.com/solution-to-chrome-cross-origin-requests-are-only-supported-for-protocol-schemes-http-data-chrome-chrome-extension-https-chrome-extension-resource/) issue.  How are you serving this angular app?  Using 'ng serve'?

Comment: Now when i switch with firefox I have : "Http failure response for (unknown url): 0 Unknown Error"